# evaluating multiple integrals

Tags: c++, matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

Is there any library to evaluate multidimensional integrals? I have at least 4 (in general much more than that), where the integrand is a combination of variables, so I cannot separate them. Do you know of any library for numerical evaluation? I'm especially looking for either matlab or c++, but I will use anything that will do the work.

Comment: Does the integrand have complex terms? Or does it blow up at some point in the domain? Why don't you just post the integral? The best way to perform an integral can be picked depending on its nature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't specify the kind of integrals or the actual dimensionality, I can only suggest that you take into account that

[image: $\int_A \int_B f(x, y) \, \mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} y = \int_A F(x) \, \mathrm{d} x$]

where the function F(x) is defined as

[image: $x \mapsto F(x) = \int_B f(x, y) \, \mathrm{d} y$]

and use this fact to compute your integrals with the usual quadrature techniques.  For example, you could use `trapz` or `quad` in MATLAB.   However, if the dimensionality is truly high, then you are better off using Monte Carlo algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

[First link off google.](http://www.feynarts.de/cuba/)

Seems pretty roboust.

Answer (score 1):

"Numerical Recipes In C" has a very nice chapter on numerical integration.

Maybe Gaussian quadrature can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is [TESTPACK](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/testpack/testpack.html) which is `C++` program which demonstrates the testing of a routine for multidimensional integration.